# Model not running after the 1st epoch

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I am trying to train a CNN model with sequential API on the CIFAR10 dataset, but somehow while training my model gets stuck after the first epoch.
I tried running nvidia-smi and found out that the my gpu usage is not very high, which is often not the case.
The following is my code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range = 40,
    width_shift_range = 0.2,
    height_shift_range = 0.2,
    shear_range = 0.2,
    zoom_range = 0.2,
    horizontal_flip = True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()

train_generator = train_datagen.flow(
                    X_train, y_train,
                    batch_size = 64)

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow(
                        X_valid, y_valid,
                        batch_size = 64)

model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', padding='same', input_shape=(32, 32, 3)))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', padding='same'))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', padding='same'))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', padding='same'))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.3))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', padding='same'))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', padding='same'))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.4))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(128, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))


model.compile(loss = "sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
              optimizer = "Adam",
              metrics = ["accuracy"])


history = model.fit(train_generator,
                    steps_per_epoch = int(X_train.shape[0] / 64),  # (number of images / batch size)
                             epochs = 50,
                             validation_data = validation_generator)
```

and this is the epoch after which the training does not proceed:

```
Epoch 1/50
703/703 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3803 - accuracy: 0.0768
```

nvidia-smi gives the following result:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 466.27       Driver Version: 466.27       CUDA Version: 11.3     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name            TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ... WDDM  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| N/A   51C    P8     3W /  N/A |    444MiB /  4096MiB |      9%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1516    C+G   Insufficient Permissions        N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A      4824    C+G   ...lPanel\SystemSettings.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A      5268    C+G   C:\Windows\explorer.exe         N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A      8268    C+G   ...b3d8bbwe\WinStore.App.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A      8612    C+G   ...nputApp\TextInputHost.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A      9232    C+G   ...5n1h2txyewy\SearchApp.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     10280    C+G   ...cw5n1h2txyewy\LockApp.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     12540    C+G   ...8wekyb3d8bbwe\Cortana.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     13164    C+G   ...y\ShellExperienceHost.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     13292    C+G   ...me\Application\chrome.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     14008    C+G   ...ekyb3d8bbwe\YourPhone.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     14420    C+G   ...wekyb3d8bbwe\Video.UI.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     15408    C+G   ...batNotificationClient.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     16084    C+G   ...ekyb3d8bbwe\HxOutlook.exe    N/A      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: You can try `steps_per_epoch = train_generator.samples // train_generator.batch_size` in `model.fit` and let us know?

Comment: I used `steps_per_epoch = train_generator.samples // train_generator.batch_size` but itr was showing another error: `'NumpyArrayIterator' object has no attribute 'samples'`

Comment: Can you try as `steps_per_epoch = len(train_generator) /batch_size` and let us know?

Comment: If this is also not working then, can you share complete code to replicate your issue? so that we can try to help you. Thanks!

Comment: It is still getting stuck. The following is the link to my code:[link](https://github.com/Saksham0207/CIFAR10/blob/master/Untitled1.ipynb)

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't specified `validation_steps` it ran into an infinite loop. You can add `validation_steps` to `model.fit` as shown below your issue will be resolved.

```
history = model.fit(train_generator,
                    steps_per_epoch = len(train_generator) // train_generator.batch_size,
                    validation_data = validation_generator,
                    validation_steps=len(validation_generator) // validation_generator.batch_size,
                    epochs = 150)
```

For complete working code you can refer this [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/chunduriv/f174b600d49defdb739d1c2d23824e6d/untitled21.ipynb).